# Interpolation error for the exponential function

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation

I'm studiyng for my exam of scientific computing, specifically to the subject of interpolation techniques, I'm stuck with this problem:

How many equally spaced nodes must be taken to interpolate the function $f(x) = \exp(x)$ on the interval $[-1,1]$, so that the interpolation error is $0.5 * 10^{-4}$?

I have no idea how to start or what should I do in the exercise. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define the interpolation technique used.  If you use linear interpolation between the nodes (which I suspect is what you are doing) you are using the first order [Taylor's series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem).  The error term is $\frac {f''(x)(x-a)^2}{2!}$.  $x-a$ is at most half your node spacing, which you can choose to get the error low enough.  What is the maximum value of $f''(x)$ on $[-1,1]$?

Comment: i think is 2.7182, right?

Comment: @Melkhiah66:  that's right, so plug that in and you can find $x-a$ from $\frac {e(x-a)^2}{2!} \lt 0.5\cdot 10^{-4}$